# Inheritance in Java that doesnt lose data

Tags: java

Can i storage all my inherited objects as ArrayList? I dont want to create new ArrayList for each object type something like:

```
ArrayList<MyObjectTypeA>
ArrayList<MyObjectTypeB>
ArrayList<MyObjectTypeC>
```

I know i can do:

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

Then cast it to valid object type, but maybe there is faster and more performanced method to do it like:

```
ArrayList<MyObject>
```

and cast it to valid object type, will i lose additional object type data or cast will bring it back to my type?

Comment: In ArrayList? it will not lose additional subtype data when i cast it back?

Comment: have your types implement a similar interface and then use the instance of to get the particular type you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyObjectTypeA` and the rest inherit from `MyObject` then you can indeed create an `ArrayList<MyObject>` and store all of them and the cast them back to the correct object type.

However, note that this is an antipattern and usually a smell of bad code. You should only be doing this if you want to use *any type* of `MyObject`. If you want to use a specific type then you should create different `List`s.

Regardless, if you are going to go through with bundling them all together in one list, at least before doing any casting you should check if the object you are casting is actually an instance of the type you are casting to like so:

```
if (object instanceof MyObjectTypeA){
  MyObjectTypeA typeA = (MyObjectTypeA) object;
} else if (object instanceof MyObjectTypeB) {
  // etc.
}
```

Note that the process of casting **does not** change the object itself. That's why the correct naming is *type casting*. You essentially declare than an instance is of a specific type. This essentially "enables" the usage of the specific type's methods and members whereas previously they were there but they were not accessible because the compiler didn't know about them (since he *thought* the type of the object did not contain such members but inside the program memory it actually *did*).

As an example, if you try cheat like so:

```
MyObjectTypeA typeA = new MyObjectTypeA();
MyObject object = (MyObject) typeA;
MyObjectTypeB typeB = (MyObjectTypeB) object;
```

This will actually compile since the compiler knows that `object` **can** be of type `MyObjectTypeB` but it will warn you that you are doing an unchecked casting (not checking with `instanceof` like I showed earlier). That specific scenario, when reaching line 3 will throw a `ClassCastException` since the interpreter will attempt to cast `object` to `MyObjectTypeB` but will fail since `object` is of type `MyObjectTypeB`.

Comment: I want to make something like server for my app, so should i create new list for new request type and manage them from RequestManager class, or create Manager for each request?

Comment: Each request should have its own request handling *method*. And all **types** of requests should have handlers under the same Manager class.

Comment: I dont need to compare them by `instanceof` because i have declared RequestType enum in supertype.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an arraylist of type base class and add to it objects of the inherited types.
`ArrayList<BaseClass>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to clearly define your objects.

For example, if you have a Class `A`, and classes `B` and `C` inherit from `A`, then yes do the following:

```
ArrayList<A> temp= new ArrayList<A>;
```

Here you will be able to call the methods you would want using polymorphism.

You should also be aware of type-safety and type-casting. The object class is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `HashMap` and store the Object as the value and the Key as the type?

```
HashMap<Type, Object> typeObjectMap = new HashMap<Type, Object>();
```